Bootstrap dropdown menu on collapse formatting
I'm trying to format the dropdown menu of my navbar when it's collapsed. Right now, it's a white background that's underneath other containers on the page. The links/:hover/overall functionality all work, it's just the formatting.
I've tried selecting .navbar-collapse, and the formatting changes accordingly, but it also affects the navbar when not collapsed. For instance, I'll change the background color and that's reflected in the dropdown, but then I have a different colored bar across my expanded navbar as well. Am I missing something in my bootstrap? Or have the wrong selector entirely?
Thank you!


<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" id="navbar-container">
    <div class="container">
      <img src="img.jpg" alt="logo">
      <!-- drop down menu on collapse -->
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navmenu">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <!-- nav bar items -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navmenu">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" target="_blank" href="link">Discord</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="submission.html">Submit A Song</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-I7E8VVD/ismYTF4hNIPjVp/Zjvgyol6VFvRkX/vR+Vc4jQkC+hVqc2pM8ODewa9r" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0pUGZvbkm6XF6gxjEnlmuGrJXVbNuzT9qBBavbLwCsOGabYfZo0T0to5eqruptLy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>




you can use media query to target only mobile

Can you please clarify, what you are trying to achieve? You said you tried to apply formatting to .navbar-collapse, but that would also affect how things look, when it is collapsed - but that is hardly possible, because that element has display: none in its collapsed state. Are you trying to format the "hamburger"-button that triggers this element - or what?
